# Realize observer in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to monitor the value of the variable in my function:

```
var initEvents = function () {
        var isValid = true;
}
```

and depending on that make this:

```
$('#someId').prop("disabled",true);
```

How can I implement it in `js`? I wanna use `observer`. Is it a good idea? Can anyone help me with realization?

Comment: can't you just make a function like 'SetValid' which sets the `isValid` variable and then disables or enables the element?

Comment: I did so, but will it be a good solution? In c#, for example, I can use events. What about js?

Comment: well. it is a working solution. you're basically making a getter/setter in that way. After a tiny bit of searching i did find something called `object.Watch` which acts like a variable event handler. but as far as i can tell it does not work on each browser. you could look in to that though

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it!